# R - Manipulate a dataframe without losing a column

Tags: r, dataframe, cbind

This most is likely a very basic question BUT I am a little stuck. I have dataframe (called B) like this

```
   mgrno  AAPL BRK  MSFT WYNN
   0001    0    0    1    2
   0003    1    0    3    0
   0004    0    1    0    2
```

What I would like to do is replace any value greater than 1 with a 1. ie the result would look like

```
  mgrno  AAPL BRK  MSFT WYNN
   0001    0    0    1    1
   0003    1    0    1    0
   0004    0    1    0    1
```

So I can get this by there with this

```
B <- as.data.frame(ifelse(B[,-1] == 0, 0, 1))
```

but I lose the mgrno column so to put the pieces back together I would need to do something like

```
temp <-B[1]
B <- as.data.frame(ifelse(B[,-1] == 0, 0, 1))
B <- cbind(temp, B)
```

There must be a neater way. Sorry to both people with this basic thing.

Answer (score 1):

`B[,-1]<-ifelse(B[,-1] == 0, 0, 1)` should do it.

Comment: short and sweet - how I wish all my code could be this simple

Answer (score 0):

We can convert to a logical matrix on a subset of dataset (excluding the first column) and convert the logical to binary with `+` and assign it back to the dataset

```
df1[-1] <- +(df1[-1] > 0)
```

---

Or a faster approach would be

```
df1[-1] <- lapply(df1[-1], function(x) as.integer(x > 0))
```

Comment: short and sweet - how I wish all my code could be this simple

Answer (score 0):

If you want to map a function like `max(x,1)` across all cells in your dataframe/matrix, here is a trick I used to use.
I'm sure there are better ways however.

```
B = data.frame(mgrno = c("001", "002", "003"),
            AAPL = c(0,1,0),
            BRK = c(0,0,1),
            MSFT = c(1,3,0),
            WYNN = c(2,0,2))

out = sapply(B[2:5], function(x) lapply(x, function(z) min(z,1)))
df = data.frame(B[,"mgrno"],out)
df
```

The names of the first column are a bit off, but that's a more trivial problem.

```
> df
  B....mgrno.. AAPL BRK MSFT WYNN
1          001    0   0    1    1
2          002    1   0    1    0
3          003    0   1    0    1
```